# SonarQube Quality Gates for Manual Measures

Tags: sonarqube

I am using some manual metrics on my SonarQube Project. I want to use my own manual metrics as a condition on a Quality Gate. I searched through documentation and internet. I could not find anything about the topic. The SonarQube allows to use only system metrics. Are there any way to use Manual Metrics on a condition in QualityGate ?

Answer (score 1):

Quality Gate conditions can actually be created based on manual metrics, but some metric types are not available: DATA, RATING and (obviously) Quality Gate status.

Comment: I am using SonarQube 4.3.2 version, however I cannot create condition based on manual metrics. When creating a condition, I could not find the metrics that are manually created. It is so strange. Do you have  any comment about it ?

Comment: What are the types of the manual metrics that you want to use? If they do not appear, then it is most probably a bug.

Comment: I had manual metrics and alerts which got converted to quality gates in version 4.4, but I cannot change the values and SonarQube tells me that they are deprecated. It is also not possible for me to add a quality gate for a manual metric. The metrics in question are integers and floats. Nothing too fancy...

Comment: Well, using SonarQube 4.5 I am able to create a quality gate condition on a manual metric, and I am quite certain that this part has not changed since 4.4. To investigate further, please post a message to the user@sonar.codehaus.org mailing list, since StackOverflow is not really suited to in-depth investigation.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. It seems that manual metrics that I create do not have the "hidden" column set to false. This seems to prevent it from being used in Quality Gates. It also causes existing entries to be marked as "DEPRECATED".

Answer (score 1):

Manual metrics are created with the `hidden` attribute set to `NULL` in the database. Changing it to `0` makes the manual metric appear in the "Add Condition" dropdown of the quality gates.

Since the manual metrics seem to work fine with the quality gates, I assume this is a bug in SonarQube.
Credit to [Stefan Egli's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609782/sonarqube-quality-gates-for-manual-measures#comment43521769_24611680) which guided me in the right direction.